# Styles of prepositional phrase, noun phrases and verb phrases

Tags: writing-style

May I ask how does a prepositional phrase, noun phrase and verb phrase sound different to you as native speakers, when they are used to convey the same meaning in a sentence?

Editors working on my essays have revised them frequently to and from each other, but I can't decide over which to use in writings of different styles, e.g., formal essay, dialogues in interview articles, and writings targeting professionals or a young readership...etc. Below please see two of the sentences revised by them. Thanks!

- Example 1:

Original version: 
Additionally, our communications technology system **is in the process of renewal**, and that has resulted in various technical constraints.

Revised version:
Since our communications technology system **is undergoing renovation**, this has resulted in various technical constraints.

- Example 2:

Original version:
Despite many being enthralled by fortune-telling, we are **the masters to decide** how our lives turn out.

Revised version:
Despite many being enthralled by fortune-telling, we are **the masters of deciding** how our lives turn out.

Comment: Your first original sentence has probably been revised because it contains an example of what Zinsser in _On Writing Well_ (p76) calls _'creeping nounism'_ and Pinker in _The Sense of Style_ (p50) calls a _'verbal coffin'_, i.e. _'The nominalization rule that takes a perfectly spry verb and embalms it into a lifeless noun..._'. Your second sentence simply uses the wrong preposition after _masters_. That said, you may get a more detailed response on the _Writing_ site: https://writing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As @Shoe said. Also, the versions may not always convey the exact same meaning.

Comment: Thank you @Shoe and Kris! But there are still some examples that seem neither verbal coffins or grammatical errors. Below please see another example:

Comment: *(Original version)* Such violations range from intervening in other jurisdictions and requesting cooperation with the judiciary without proper grounds **to refusing the decentralisation of power and the restrictions set out in the constitution.**

*(Revised version)* Such violations range from intervening in other jurisdictions and requesting cooperation with the judiciary without proper grounds **to refusing to decentralise power and refusing to accept the restrictions set out in the constitution.**

Comment: The problem with the original is the noun __decentralisation__ . The revised version also rejects the notion that the verb __refusing__ can be applied to both the decentralisation  and to the restrictions.

Comment: @Shoe, noted, so maybe in this case, the noun **decentralisation** and the collocation between **"refusing"** and **"decentralisation"** are not idiomatic. But if there are no such two problems, how would you decide between using a noun phrase or verb phrase? E.g., some considerations may be the effect on tone, the formality of the text...etc? Please kindly advise. Thanks!

Comment: There is a difference between _refuse + noun_ and _refuse to + verb_. If I refuse an invitation to a party, I decline the invitation. If I refuse to invite, then I am the one issuing invitations - or not in this case. I think you have an interesting question. But the comments section is not the place to give good, supported answers. And as I said above, the _Writing_ site is probably the best place to ask about the tone and formality of a given text.

Comment: Thank you @Shoe!

Comment: I don't agree with either of the edits; neither makes the wording any more simple or direct. Assuming I felt the need to change them at all, I would have made the original *is being renewed* and the second *the masters of how*. But none of that has anything to do with grammar; it's entirely subjective.

Comment: @JasonBassford, Thanks for your advice - your edits look good! May I ask in professional editing, apart from making wordings more simple or direct, if there are other general *objective* rationales underlying the choices between different kinds of phrases, when conveying the same meaning?

Comment: For example, two different editors had made contrasting revisions to my writings, by switching between a progressive verb phrase and a to-infinitive:

Comment: **Example 1:** *(Original version)* At the heart of this phenomenon lies the failure of those divisions **in establishing** the segmented management of distribution and specialised market strategy, thwarting the enhancement of their competence and status... *(Revised version)* At the heart of this phenomenon lies the failure of those divisions **to establish** the segmented management of distribution and specialised market strategy, thwarting the enhancement of their competence and status...

Comment: **Example 2:** *(Original version)* In this regard, I am inclined to a concessionary policy to motivate grown-up only sons and daughters to bear the onus **to support** their parents. *(Revised version)* In this regard, I am inclined to a concessionary policy to motivate grown-up only sons and daughters to bear the onus **of supporting** their parents. – Jane 5 mins ago

Comment: I took it the progressive verb phrases sound more **static** than to-infinitives, and may make the writings **flat**? If this is true, I wonder if **"static" phrases** (like progressive verb, prepositional and noun phrases) could be used more in formal writings aiming at giving factual information, like annual reports...etc. While **“active” phrases** (like to-infinitive) can be used more in those looking at drawing readerships, like magazine interview articles...etc. Many thanks!

Comment: In the absence of real syntactic or semantic problems, the only arbiter of which of two edits is better in terms of style is which ends up (1) being most consistent with the rest of the text and (2) which would be most appreciated by the target audience. But everything being equal, it's ultimately up to the author what happens with their text.

Comment: Many thanks for your advice, @JasonBassford, which is very helpful!